# How can I apply an htaccess rewrite rule to a URL containing a linefeed character (%0A)?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm running into bad URLs that contain an escaped line-feed in the following format:

```
http://domain.com/%0Apath/to/file.txt
```

However, even if I try the most global rewrite possible...

```
RewriteRule ^.*$ /path/to/file.txt [R=301,L]
```

...Apache still throws a 404:

```
The requested URL / path/to/file.txt was not found on this server.

(Note the space.)
```

How can I gracefully intercept these bad URLs and route them to the right destination?

Comment: Did you ever get the answer for this problem?

Answer (score 3):

I had the same Problem. I fixed it with the help of sarumont's answer.

Example URL, found in Webmaster Tools:

```
/dummy-url/dummy-%0A%0Afull-version-download
```

Rewrite Rule that I added in Apache config:

```
RewriteRule ^/dummy-url/dummy-[\n\r]+full-version-download$ /dummy-url/dummy-full-version-download [L,R=301]
```

Comment: This is the correct answer. The `[\n\r]` characters are needed because a wildcard such as `.+` will cause a 400 Bad Request.

Answer (score 1):

`^.*$` won't span the linefeed. Try a plain `.*`. Alternatively, try matching on the newline characters: `[\r\n]`.

Answer (score 1):

Adding `\s` to the RewriteRule should fix it.

```
RewriteRule ^\s.*$ /path/to/file.txt [R=301,L]
```

More specifically as a catch-all

```
RewriteRule ^\s(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 1):

This is very old question but I think none of the answer are right so posting an answer:

Replace your rule with this:

```
RewriteRule .* /path/to/file.txt [R=301,L]
```