# Allow %0A in url RewriteRule with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, curl

I've got a rewriterule in my .htaccess which allows me to add unlimited parameters separated by /'s.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?params=$1 [L,NC]
```

This works properly untill I send an urlencoded string to it (using cURL) with an encoded \n in it (%0A).

So `server/param1/param2/param3text` works, but `server/param1/param2/param3text1%0Aparam3text2` doesn't.

I found one Q on Stack Overflow mentioning a similar problem:

[How can I apply an htaccess rewrite rule to a URL containing a linefeed character (%0A)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8751110/how-can-i-apply-an-htaccess-rewrite-rule-to-a-url-containing-a-linefeed-characte)

But I *can't/don't know how to* implement `[\r\n]` in my `(.*)`.

Any help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so first, I had to add a check to make sure that the file didn't exist (the two RewriteCond's take care of that).  Then I had to create a pattern that matched any character, or a `\r` or a `\n` that was matched one or more times(`+`). The zero or more times operator (`*`) didn't return the results properly.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^((.|\r|\n)+)/? index.php?params=$1 [L,NC]
```

Comment: This answer is the right one, this one worked. But if you're reading this, please consider setting setup a secure connection in order to prevent @Ed-AITpro's problem.

Answer (score 0):

You must utilize `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable to grab actual path from original Apache web server request.

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^params=.+ [NC]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+[^/]+/([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?params=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Then inside `index.php` check `$_SERVER["QUERY_STRING"]` for the full unadulterated path with `%0A` in it.

Comment: This one didn't result in an error, but it took the directory my system runs in as a parameter too.

Comment: Didn't know that you have a URL like: `http://domain.com/dir/param1/param2/param3text1%0Aparam3text2`. Edited it to take care of it.

Answer (score 0):

Just an FYI here: A common hacking method called Whitespace filtering uses %0A

> Filtering can be bypassed on the space character by using alternative
>   whitespace characters to the space character (%20). Most SQL engines
>   consider a line return (%0a in a *NIX environment, %0a%0d in a Windows
>   environment), tab characters, or the + character as valid whitespace: